# .getJSON versus .ajax error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I'm trying to get my error function called when an external json fails to load.

This works fine with .getJSON, but doesn't with .ajax. Can anyone take a look at the code and tell me if I missed something?

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8C7Hb/

```
$.getJSON( "http://foo.com/bar.json", function() {
    $('#method1_result').html('Success');
}).fail(function() { $('#method1_result').html('Fail'); });

$.ajax({
    url: "http://foo.com/bar.json",
    dataType: "jsonp", 
    success: function(data) {
         $('#method2_result').html('Success'); 
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#method2_result').html('Error');
    }
}).fail(function() { $('#method2_result').html('Fail'); });
```

Thank you.

Comment: `dataType` should be `json`, as a sidenote.

Comment: @jAndy : actually i'm trying to get jsonp to fail correctly.

Comment: then you're comparing apples with oranges. `getJSON()` will also set the dataType to `json`. `jsonp` is a whole different story.

Comment: you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584/1385672  the last paragraph

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ thanks, too bad the JSONRequest design proposal doesn't seem to have any traction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, jQuery doesn't call `error` on a failed jsonp call (which is what `.fail` binds to). But, luckily this is a common problem and there is a solution to it: https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in the comments, `.getJSON` uses the *dataType* `json`. By explicitly setting the *dataType* to `jsonp` in your `.ajax()` call, you force jQuery to assume you are going to retrieve a *true* json with padding-response (which basically means, dynamic scripttag insertion).

Setting the *dataType* to `json` will also "fail correctly".